# How to determine element coordinates in scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a `div` element with vertical scrolling. It has `span` elements with text in it. How can I get the coordinates of these `span` elements. But I don't want it relative to the scroll position.

For example, in the `div`, lets say its 400px width, 1000px in height (but the view height is 500px), and its scrolled half way vertically. Then in the center of the view, I see a text, and if I click on it, I want the coordinate like (200, 250)

How can I get coordinates that are absolute to the `div` container?

Answer (score 1):

Use element.getBoundingClientRect? (Subtract the container's top if you want it relative to the container.)

```js
function client() {
  alert(document.getElementById('child').getBoundingClientRect().top);
}

function local() {
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  var containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  var child = document.getElementById('child');
  var childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
  localTop = childRect.top - containerRect.top;
  alert(localTop);
}
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  overflow:scroll;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-top:100px;
}

#child {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Test</div>
  <div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div>
  <div id="child">Item of interest</div>
    <div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div><div>Test</div>
</div>
<button onclick="client()">Global top</button>
<button onclick="local()">Local top</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the scrollable div has an id of 'myDiv' and one element inside the div has an id of 'element1'. To find its true 'top' value in javascript try this:

```
alert($('myDiv').css('top') + $('element1').css('top'));
```